# Distribution of distance from origin for uniformly randomly chosen point in annular region

Tags: probability, circles, uniform-distribution

I have uniformly distributed nodes over an annular region RI<r<RO.
I would like to compute the PDF of the distance from any chosen node to the center of the annular.
In the case of $R_I = 0$ (circle), the PDF is simply given by $r^2 / R_O^2$ as solved here [for $R_I = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235997/distribution-of-distance-from-origin-for-uniformly-randomly-chosen-point-in-circ?newreg=3a7abac83e7f46108e44b13d4e8cfb78)
The logic in my case is to have PDF = $r^2 - (R_I)^2 / (R_O^2 - R_I^2)$. However, when I simulated it in MATLAB, this formula doesn't match with the simulation!

Could anyone help, please?

Comment: When you say annular region, you mean centered around the origin, right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the pdf given for $\ R_I\ $ in the answer you cite is $\ \frac{2r}{R_O^2}\ $, not $\ \frac{r^2}{R_O^2}\ $, as you say here.  The latter is the *cumulative distribution function* of the point's distance from the origin.  For $\ R_I\ne0\ $ the  cumulative distribution function of the point's distance from the origin is
$$
\frac{r^2-RI^2}{RO^2-RI^2}\ . 
$$
for $\ RI\le r\le RO\ $, and the pdf is the derivative of this:
$$
\frac{2r}{RO^2-RI^2}\ .
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!