# How to find the $CDF$ of the distance from origin of a uniformly random point in a unit circle?

Tags: probability

If $(x, y)$ is a uniformly randomly chosen point on a unit circle with radius $1$, then the distance of said point to origin is $D = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

How would I find the $CDF$ of $D$?

I think the PDF is of $D$ is $2D$ (using the approach outlined here: [Distribution of distance from origin for uniformly randomly chosen point in circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235997/distribution-of-distance-from-origin-for-uniformly-randomly-chosen-point-in-circ)) but am not sure how to get the $CDF$ from this. If I try taking the CDF by taking the double integral of the $PDF$, I get a really complicated integral evaluation. Am I doing this right or is there a more simple and intuitive way to get the $CDF$ of $D$?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean (x,y) is chosen *within* the unit circle?

Comment: You don't need to evaluate any pdf, the answer is fairly intuitive. The set of points that fall within distance $D$ to the origin are the points in the circle with radius $D$ centered at the origin.

Comment: $\int_0^D 2x \, dx = D^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming that you meant the point was chosen uniformly in the unit disc)

The area of a circle of radius $r$ is $\pi r^2$, and the uniform measure on the circle is a constant density of $1/\pi$.  So the probability of being inside a circle of radius $r$ should be $r^2$.

Thus the cdf $P(D <= r) = r^2$ for $r\in[0,1]$ (and it is $0$ for $r<0$ and $1$ for $r> 1$).  From this you can get the pdf is $2r 1_{[0,1]}(r)$.